# Installing Symfony 2 on Fedora 15

Tags: symfony, fedora

I've got a problem when i try to install Symfony 2:
I extract the content of the tgz file into `var/www/html` directory and then i go on `http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/config.php` and it says that i need to change the permissions of `app/cache/*` and `app/logs/*`. The problem is that I tried all the solutions in the doc

Answer (score 0):

Which solutions exactly did you try? Did you chmod those folders?

If your web server and command line user are different, that can also cause problems with those two folders. Check [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) for their `umask` solution and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried to chmod them with root privileges.
The acl command doesn't work because i get "Option -m: Invalid argument near character 3" error...
I also tried to add the umask thing...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and SELinux was responsible.

To figure out if SELinux is the source of your problem, turn it off by typing: `setenforce Permissive` on the command line.
If the script works, then you have to configure SELinux properly.